# Using assignment operator inside of expression

Tags: java, operators, assignment-operator, operator-precedence

Running this code will return 11 while I was expecting 20. Why is that so?

```
int x = 1;
int y = x + (x = 10);
System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: Why were you expecting 20?

Comment: Evaluation is left to right.

Comment: @NicholasK since i dont assignment (x = 10) and i thought assignment will be evaluated first and then x value  will be 10

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline got it. so (x = 10) parenthesis doesn't count?

Comment: in the second line "x" keeps being 1 an then change the value

Comment: @bhusak Parenthesis just affect parsing, so  'x = 10 + x` is different from `(x = 10) + x`.

Comment: @Jose The left-hand-side of the expression ` x + (x = 10)` is evaluated first, so after the first step it's the equivalent of `1 + (x = 10)` and the fact that `1` came from `x` is no longer relevant.

Comment: Why would you write it that way instead of `int x = 10; int y = x + x;`? [Write dumb code](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html)

Comment: @ElliottFrisch i'm not writing this kind of code. just trying to understand java basics. and thanks for the article, going to read it asap :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evaluation is from left to right. So

```
int y = x + (x = 10);
```

is (with `x` initially `1`):

```
int y = 1 + 10;
```

Putting the assignment in `()` doesn't make it come first. It just ensures that it's a valid expression, since `y = x + x = 10` would be `y = (x + x) = 10` which would require assigning to something (`x + x`) that wasn't a variable.

If you want 20, put the assignment first:

```
int y = (x = 10) + x;
```

---

Of course, the **vast** majority of the time, it's best to avoid these kinds of side-effects and assign `x` a value *outside* the expression, breaking the expression up if necessary. Assignment-within-expression can be useful sometimes (particularly `while ((blah = getNextBlah()) != null)` sort of things), but only in limited situations.